# Flutter/Dart - Use something like ChangeNotifier or setState within Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-change-notifier

I'm using `SocialProvider` with `ChangeNotifier`. I want it to update its `Consumer` listener widgets once the user logs in and after posting to a database on the web.

Currently, I'm calling a `Future` method which inserts the new values to a Shared Preferences file upon a successful http post, but this won't update the UI until a call is made to a page which loads shared preferences.

In order to see an instant update, is there any way to access something like the `ChangeNotifier` or other kind of `setState` type function from within a `Future`? Here's the future;

```
Future<void> postSocialData(String email) async {
    final url = "http://example.com/example.php?currentemail=$email"          

  final response = await http.get(url);
  String currentuserid;

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    currentuserid =  response.body;

      setSharedPreferences(
      currentavatar: "http://example.com/" + response.body + "-user.jpg",
      currentemail: email,
      currentlogged: true,
      currentuserid: currentuserid,
    );

    print(response.body);

  } else {

    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully post social data.');
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get an instant update from a `Future` method?

Comment: if you have a `Future` use `FutureBuilder` to rebuild your UI

Comment: The future builder builds the user info once they've logged in. But how do I present the default user information until they login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was able to insert the `Future<void> postSocialData` within the scope of the `class SocialProvider with ChangeNotifier` itself and hence use The `ChangeNotifier` within the Future to alert the `Consumers/listeners`.